# Como crio um tema para textarea igual do VS Code?

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Eu queria fazer no textarea no html que ele tivesse cor diferente a cada caracteres.
Mas quando uso color do css tudo fica igual.
Como posso sai desse problema?

```html
<textarea style='color: blue'>Hello World!</textarea>
```

Comment: Você quer colocar uma cor diferente pra cada caractere que o usuário digita?

Comment: Ou melhor ainda [Como estilizar elementos dentro da tag <textarea>?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/275602/5878)

Comment: Sim. Eu queria criar um Web Ide pra linguagem JSON,SQL e linguagem do meu amigo MSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso não é um problema, você pediu que isso acontecesse, você aplicou uma propriedade ao elemento pai e seus filhos estão recebendo a herança de seu pai. De uma olhada [Cascata e herança.](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/Getting_Started/Cascading_and_inheritance)

Como você disse

> Eu queria fazer no textarea no html que ele tivesse cor diferente a cada caracteres.

Então simples, é so agrupar cada caractere em um `span` tag. E depois formatar com o css criei um exemplo para você.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

  <textarea style='color: blue'>
    <span style="color:red;">H</span>
    <span style="color:blue;">e</span>
    <span style="color:green;">l</span>
    <span style="color:pink;">l</span>
    <span style="color:orange;">o</span>
    <span style="color:orangered;">W</span>
    <span style="color:orchid;">o</span>
    <span style="color:plum;">r</span>
    <span style="color:salmon;">l</span>
    <span style="color:sienna;">d</span>
    <span style="color:yellow;">!</span>
  </textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

Bricadeira :). Você viu que isso não resolveu o que você queria. Isso porque o navegador não renderizou as tags `<span>`. A tag `<textarea>` é uma tag para uma caixa de texto e o que for escrito dentro dela sera exibido no navegador. Foi o que aconteceu com o `<span>` tag. Você pode aplicar a cor que quiser no `<textarea>`, mas isso vai valer para todos os caracteres que contém o `<textarea>`. Infelizmente não é possivel formatar cada parte de um texto de um `<textarea>` e isso vale também para os `<input>` com type atributo `email`, `text`, `number`, `tel`, etc. O máximo que você conseguiria fazer é transformar o `<textarea>` em um editor **WYSIWYG** leia mais [AQUI](https://www.satellasoft.com/?materia=transformando-textarea-em-um-editor-de-texto-com-ckeditor).

Answer (score 2):

para transformar seu `<textarea>` em um editor de código, você precisa de um Editor de Texto, como estes exemplos:

https://codemirror.net/

https://ace.c9.io/

Cada um deles tem seu guia de implementação, um exemplo básico abaixo com o CodeMirror (meu favorito):

```
<!-- Create a simple CodeMirror instance -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/codemirror.css"> //caminho do css
    <script src="lib/codemirror.js"></script> // caminho do JS principal

    <!--textarea do seu html -->
    <textarea id="myTextarea"></textarea>

<!--script que vai nicializar o CodeMirror em seu textarea -->
    <script>
      var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('myTextarea'), {
        lineNumbers: true
      });
    </script>
```

Boa sorte